# Bayes theorem worded problem

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Consider an island with n + 2 inhabitants. One of the inhabitants is murdered.
The police know for sure that one of the remaining n + 1 inhabitants must be the killer
and forensic experts find a particular DNA profile at the crime scene. It is known that this
particular DNA profile occurs in a fraction p of the population, i.e., every inhabitant has
probability p of having this particular DNA profile, independently of the other inhabitants.
The police decides to screen all inhabitants for the DNA profile. The first person they screen
is Rick Random and he turns out to have the DNA profile.

Let E be the event of finding Rick Random’s particular DNA profile at the crime scene.
Let R be the event that Rick Random is the killer

Given $\mathbb P (E|R) = 1$. Find $\mathbb P (E|R^C)$

My first attempt is $\mathbb P (E|R^c) = \frac{(n+2)p-2}{n}$ however I'm not sure.

Comment: perhaps include your attempt rather than telling us your answer?

Comment: of the n+2 population a fraction p have the DNA profile. So (n+2)p, then subtract 2 since the dead guy and Rick are not being considered. Really it's a guess.

Comment: If $p$ is less than $\frac{2}{n+2}$ does this give sensical results? Based on the problem description it seems like $p=0.0000000001$ and $n=3$ are perfectly valid parameters, but it seems like it gives an odd probability for Rick not being the killer.

Comment: I wonder if there is a relationship between $P(E|R)$ and $P(E|R^c)$ and $p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice: " every inhabitant has probability $p$ of having this particular DNA profile, *independently* of the other inhabitants. "

So what is the probability that the killer had the profile under the condition that Rick Random is not the killer?

(PS: $\mathsf P(E\mid R)=1$ indicates that the police are assuming that the evidence was certainly left by the killer, not possibly by an uninvolved islander.)

Comment: So with $(n+1)p -1$ people equally likely to have the profile given Rick isn't the killer then $\mathbb P(E|R^c) = \frac{1}{(n+1)p -1}$ ?

Comment: No.  Independence.  The probability that an individual has the DNA profile is $p$ and this is *independent* of any other individual. So, what is the probability that *the killer* has the profile, when given that Rick and the killer are not the same individual ?

Comment: so just $p$?...